# How can I place components of my amplifier design between the pads of an SMA connector?

Tags: altium, design, lna

I want to place some of my amplifier components between the pads of an SMA connector.

Should I change some design rule or is the problem in the choice of the right footprint?

I added an image of my work and the aimed design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could fit more components if you make a copy of the component, and then edit your current footprint, rename it etc so as to reduce the ground pad widths to allow for more space inside the SMA zone. Also you may consider reducing the width of the SMA's centre pin solder pad to also allow more routing space as required, but still enough of a pad to allow for a strong and reliable solder joint... If your SMA connector is board-edge solder mounted on top and bottom, made for 1.6mm or 1mm PCB thickness then the mechanical strength required by the SMA may be enough from the ground pins on either side, and underneath the board etc. So in this case you may reduce the centre pad width even more, but keeping in mind the 50 Ohms trace width requirements for your circuit etc. Change of "clearance" design rules may also be required (as a separate task) for when you do the DRC but that should be easy to adjust... Good luck !